# Why do these weird characters appear on IntelliJ Idea and Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

These weird characters appeared when I installed Android Studio from the official page (Android Studio shows this too). I ran my Eset Nod32 antivirus and it says everything is alright. Does somebody know how to fix this, please?

[image: Android Studio main menu displaying werid characteres.]

Comment: Have you checked your language settings?

Comment: I have the same problem now with android-studio after I had to reinstall it once (the first run it was readable but I chose the wrong user-dir). After dozens of tries I never succeed in having readable characters anymore. BTW: If I copy & paste it, it becomes readable in an editor, so it's a display-issue I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It can be due to the font set for menus being corrupt. Change the font in *File* > *Settings* > *Appearance & Behavior* > *Appearance* and see if it renders correctly, in which case you'll have to reinstall that font in your computer or just use another one.